# title-match on application pinned to windows taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar, r

**Q:** How do I add command-line arguments to a pinned application and still have it match?

My habits/workflow have a number of apps "pinned" to the windows taskbar, so that `Win-#` will "always" switch me to the correct window.

[image: image of taskbar pinned icons]

(I'm an emacs/ess user for R, no RStudio.) If I have a plot already open, then `Win-2` will switch me to the plot window immediately. However, if a plot has not completed yet, then pressing `Win-2` will *start* a new instance of that application. In this case, the icon properties are:

> Target: `C:\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\Rterm.exe`
>
> Start in: `C:\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64`
>
> Shortcut key: `None`
>
> Run: `Normal Window`

I want to set it up so that inadvertently pressing `Win-2` while no plot exists will not start a new instance of `Rterm`. One mitigating step might be to have `Rterm` immediately exit by adding `--help` to the target, but doing so causes the window-name match to fail, and any subsequent plots opening up will not use that taskbar position.

[image: image of taskbar pinned icons plus extra graphic window]

Is there a way to add arguments that will not break title-matching? I *never* intend to start R with that icon (always within emacs/ess), so if there is a way to have it never start an app (just switch to it if created elsewhere), that would be good, too.

(A solution will most likely be windows-centric: R has no control or input on this, I believe.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this question has little to do with the `R` Statistical Programming Language.

It is more related to the *Microsoft* *Windows* **10** Operating System.

I think that you can start building your solution to this problem by creating an icon on the desktop.

[image: Creating an Icon on the Desktop]

Here, you add whatever arguments you need on the Command-Line of the ShortCut represented by the Desktop Icon.

[image: Naming the Desktop Icon]

You give the Desktop Icon a name, of course.

[image: The Created Desktop Icon]

And you have your Mighty Desktop Icon created for the User's Delight.

[image: The TaskBar]

You drag it on the TaskBar.

[image: Triggering the Windows-3 Key Combination]

You press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and there you get your Static Software Application launched into effect.

Now, by analyzing the output of the `Rterm --help` Command-Line, you might find a switch that does not start a new instance of *Rterm* while no plot exists.

***UPDATE:***

I think that we might avoid getting the help of an *Rterm* Expert, @r2evans. I have come up with an One-Liner that you might try.

Just change above the `cmd.exe /c pause` One-Liner with the `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.Exe -Command "If ((Get-Process -Name RTerm) -Eq $()) {Exit-PSSession}"` One-Liner.

In short, instead of firing up the *Microsoft* *Windows* **10** Command-Line PreProcessor, it fires up the *Microsoft* *Windows* *PowerShell* Shell-Scripting Environment just in order to feed it a simple `If` Statement that checks if a plot is running and it just exits if there is no plot.

If there is a plot, then pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> ShortCut Key Combination you just switch to your existing plot.

Comment: So the fix is to not pin the actual application icon but a shortcut to it. Interesting ... I doubted that it would work but tested first. (The issue is not determine a replacement for `--help`, it's having a command-line argument in "Target" that does not cause a title/app match to fail. It appears that shortcut links are handled differently.) Thanks!

Comment: Your Issue is not trivial. What you need is both an _Rterm_ Expert and a Shell-Scripting Expert. The _Rterm_ Expert will extract from the `Rterm --help` Command-Line the Switches that you may need. The Shell-Scripting Expert - if they really *are* an expert - will manage to write a Single _Rterm_ Command-Line that will do all of the Monkey Tricks in a Single MouthFul, in the `cmd.exe /c pause` Style. Otherwise, they will have to write a _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _PowerShell_ Shell-Script that will look for the Process using its `Rterm` Name and will bail out if there is no such Process. Tricky.

Comment: I think that I have managed somehow to avoid reaching the help of an _Rterm_ Expert, @r2evans. I have just updated the Answer. Check it out and ping me if you have trouble setting it up.

Comment: There was never a need for an "rterm expert": the addition of `--help` has *always worked* in that the window (if pressed without a plot present) does not remain open. The problem has always been about how to add *some argument* to the Target application and have follow-on real-plots still use that pinned icon. While it works with `cmd` (set the Target to `cmd /?` and all instances of `cmd` still use that pinned icon), it does not work that way for Rterm. (Now the issue is that Windows has changed the icon to a default "link" and will not let me change it back.)

Comment: Indeed, the `--help` Command-Line Switch, as the `-h`, the `/h`, the `-?` and the `/?` Command-Line Switches are working for most of the Command-Line Static Software Applications. Not only that there is no need for an _Rterm_ Expert for handling this Issue, but it definitely does not have anything to do with the `R` Statistical Programming Language. Still, the `Rterm --help` Solution is just a Work-Around that succeeds due to a Side-Effect. The _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _PowerShell_ One-Liner from my Update of my Answer does the Trick in the correct way.

Comment: Also, I do not think that there is a way to edit the TaskBar-Pinned Tiles. One has just to remove them and redo the whole process from the beginning.

Comment: Right-click the pinned-icon, the right-click on the name (above "Unpin from the taksbar"), then select Properties.

Comment: While I agree that this has nothing to do with the R programming language, the fact that `cmd` (for example) *will match* the title if the pinned icon has `/?` appended to its Target line, yet Rterm *will not match* with `--help` appended seems now specific to R (or perhaps specific to something not-Microsoft). I don't know if this inconsistency affects other applications.

Comment: Cool. So one can edit the TaskBar-Pinned Tiles. I still do not see how the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System has irreversibly changed the Icon to a Link.



I do not seem to get the _matching_ that you are describing.



Also, `--help` is definitely _not_ a Command-Line Switch Specific to the `R` Statistical Programming Language. I do not see why it is behaving differently to the case of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Command-Line PreProcessor. It is just a Standard Switch for getting the Help Information about any Static Command-Line Software Application.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting how it behaves with the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _PowerShell_ One-Liner that I have detailed in my Update in my Answer that appears above.

Comment: It does not work, likely for the same reason: *because the title of the window (`Rterm`) does not match the Target (`%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.Exe -Command "If ((Get-Process -Name RTerm) -Eq $()) {Exit-PSSession}"`)*. Perhaps I'm missing something you are suggesting. The reason I have [tag:r] tagged here is because it seems anything other than this shortcut-workaround requires having R installed and available to test and see what happens. Thank you for the shortcut-workaround, it works well enough to fix the symptom.

Comment: You're welcome, @r2evans, but still, I verily see no such matching ever being performed between any Title of a Window and anything else. A Title of a Window is just a Piece of Information maintained by a Process. The Target is the Process that the Desktop Icon / ShortCut / Link / TaskBar-Pinned Tile / Start Screen-Pinned Tile or whatever you have is firing up.

Comment: In the case of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _PowerShell_ One-Liner, by pressing on the TaskBar-Pinned Tile you are instructing the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System to start the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _PowerShell_ Shell-Scripting Environment so that it looks for the _Rterm_ Process. If it does not find it, then it just exits. It is the same thing that your `Rterm --help` Work-Around used to do, but in a more explicit and direct way.

Comment: ... *but the one-liner does not work*, so it's neither more explicit nor direct. If you say that there is no title-matching, then ... **who knows**. When I (1) start fresh; (2) plot something, the window appears; (3) pin the icon; (4) plot something, old icon re-used; (5) add ` --help` to Target; (6) plot something, old icon *not used* ... that suggests that the mere presence of additional text in the Target is causing Windows to not associate the new plot window with the pinned icon. I think the only way to truly answer this dilemma is to find out what is really happening there.

Comment: I think that simply the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System has not been designed in order to work this way. I have tested my One-Liner and it is working very well. Of course, I have tested it using my _NotePad++_ Static Software Application. In your Environment, it might behave differently. Still, my assumption is that you set your Environment up in a certain way and then you start working. For me, it works very well. I do not fully understand why you are editing the Icons during your work.

Comment: Also, I do not understand how you are pining your Icon. Are you able to drag the Newly-Created Window onto the Task-Bar?! For me, it does not work this way.

Comment: Indeed, if you edit your TaskBar-Pinned Tile _after_ it has been fired up, it might simply lose its association with the Window (in fact with the Process) that it has just fired up. Maybe this is what you are referring to through the _matching_ term. As I have just previously said, if one edits the TaskBar-Pinned Tile _after_ its firing up, anything might happen.